# Why do I have to refresh the page with this Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
<script 
    type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q= Nas&max-results=8&orderby=relevance&alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=showMyVideos2">
</script>
```

When i change the search query, I have to refresh the page to see it. Why is that? Do I need AJAX? why?

Thanks

Comment: How do you change the query? Whenever you change the source of a script tag, the browser reloads the script afaik.

Comment: How are you calling the search? Can you paste some additional code?

Comment: Answer above commentators question first.

Comment: i change the source directly and save...

Comment: Do you mean you change the HTML file and save it? Of course you have to reload the page then, the browser does not get notified that the source was changed.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess here: You are saying that if the results change but you reload the page where the script file is loaded, they don't change for you (immediately). This is expected because the script file can be cached by the browser. Forcing a refresh will likely force a reload of the script file so then the problem goes away.

Look at the response header output (e.g. using something like http://web-sniffer.net/) and notice the cache policy for the script file returned from the service specifies a max age of 300 seconds:

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=300, no-transform
```

If you really need instant updates rather than once every 5 minutes and your page is generated by a server side application, you could work around this by appending some unimportant data to the end of the script URL (for example, a random number or a GUID) so each URL is unique and it won't be loaded from the browser cache. It looks like the service allows this:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q= Nas&max-results=8&orderby=relevance&alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=showMyVideos2&987654321

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q= Nas&max-results=8&orderby=relevance&alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=showMyVideos2&123456789

Notice the extra parameter at the end of each URL, but both appear to successfully return the same.